# Bitlocker To Go drive is mounted as Read Only after it's unlocked

Tags: windows-8, encryption, mount, usb-storage, bitlocker

A while back I encrypted an external USB drive (NTFS) with Bitlocker To Go on my Windows 7 PC.

Now, when I connect the drive to my Windows 8 PC, I enter the Bitlocker password for the drive when prompted and the drive is mounted. I can see all contents, however the drive is mapped read-only (Read Only status on drive is reported in Disk Management). I have no options to turn off the Read Only setting if I right click the drive in Computer, or anywhere in the Manage Bitlocker control panel.

How can I mount the drive without write protection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unplugging and power cycling the drive didn't resolve the issue, but a reboot did. Should have tried that first. Now the drive mounts as writable after entering the Bitlocker password when it's attached.